# Thunderbird delivering emails to wrong inbox

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I have Thunderbird set up to use IMAP on GMail, and I have a whole slew of filters. I have an Inbox, a folder named "important" and about 30 other folders.

My first filter moves messages from people in my personal address book into this "important" folder. The next 30 move mail from various marketers and mailing lists into inboxes for each. The filters appear to be working correctly, but...

I am getting messages from two people who are not in my personal address book, arriving in the "important" folder, and I can't work out why.

As an experiment I moved them back to the inbox and ran all my filters on the inbox, and this did NOT move them. Conclusion - its not the filter.

So it appears that something other than a filter is placing the mail from these people into my "important" folder. I have checked the set up on my google account and can see nothing that might be causing this.

Has anyone got any suggestions as to what might be causing these messages to be wrongly classified?

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion on that topic in the [GMail Help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/vJH91uY6lB0).

In the second post, it is explained how to turn off the Important folder. In the first post, a reference is made to [how importance works in GMail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/186543?hl=en). Just check if any of the points stated there apply to you.

Kind regards.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Have disabled everything that points to and messages are still being marked as important.

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your filter is also moving email that is flagged as 'Important' by the sender? Some email clients allow outgoing email to be flagged this way, and may even allow for all email sent to be automatically flagged as 'Important'. That's easy enough to test; just send yourself an email from an address not in your address book, but flag it as 'Important'.